# Batch File Read Contents No Extension on File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
for /r "C:\File Folder" %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="FoundFile" set p=%%~dpnxa
for /f "delims=. tokens=1*" %%A in ("%p%") do set Build=%%B
```

> ```
> CMD>if "FoundFile" == "FoundFile" set p=C:\File Folder\SubFolder\FoundFile
> CMD>for /F "delims=. tokens=1*" %A in ("C:\File Folder\SubFolder\FoundFile") do set Build=%B
> CMD>set Build=
> ```

The search function seems to find the file I'm looking for. The FoundFile doesn't have an extension. When I run that same command in a batch file while it's in the same folder and I just give it a file name no filepath it runs perfectly. As soon as I try to run the script from a remote folder and give it the full path it runs everything but can't get the data needed out of the file. I'm guessing it can't open it to read it and fill in the variable Build

The file that it's reading is getting an extension that was written inside the file from another program. I'm needing that extension to continue with my script.

How do I read the file that doesn't have an extension, I can't "add an extension".

Comment: Your code and the output did not fit together, so I edited in the file name shown in the output – please check and correct, if applicable! Anyway, I cannot reproduce the problem you are describing; are you using this code inside of another parenthesised block, like a loop or something? if so, take a look at [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and apply it on variable `Build`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `"usebackq tokens=1* delims=."`

`for /f` when applied to a quoted string processes the string, not the filename inside the quotes.

I put `delims=` last because of ambiguity in the command - as written in your original, the delimiter set might be `.` or (`.` and <kbd>Space</kbd>)